# ICSharpCode Under Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, icsharpcode

Has anyone tried getting the ICSharpCode.TextEditor library to work in Ubuntu under Mono? I know it uses quite a few P/Invoke methods, If anyone found a way to get around these it would be good help to know how it was done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about SharpDevelop there? Have you looked at [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), it's already ported.

Answer (score 1):

[Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com) has it's own text editor that works on Windows or Linux.